# Updating List view from database

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I feel like i am missing something simple and stupid. I have a list view with a few buttons at the top. The list view is initially populated with data. When you click a button the list view is supposed to populate its self based on a changed variable in the Where statement. In reality i could probably just start a new List activity but i feel like there is a better way.

I have been reading up on `CursorAdapter.changeAdapter()` and `notifydatasetchanged()` I have not implemented this yet because i am having a more basic problem.

I can successfully query the database and display the static results in the list. When i try to break process into steps i am running into an ERROR: Invalid statement in `fillWindow`. The best i understand this is caused by improperly closing cursors databases and DB helpers and for this reason people use content providers.

For now i am just trying to get this to work.

```
    public class DListView extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener{

public static final String NAME = "Name";

public static final String DESCRIPT = "Description";

public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Table";


public static final String DAY = "Day_id";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Cursor c = null;    

private String[] colsfrom = {"_id", NAME, DESCRIPT, DAY};
private int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text01, R.id.text02, R.id.text03, R.id.text04};

public int b = 0;

public int d = 0; 

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drinklistview);

        View left = findViewById(R.id.left_button);
        left.setOnClickListener(this);
        View right = findViewById(R.id.right_button);
        right.setOnClickListener(this);

        Intent thisIntent = getIntent();
        b = thisIntent.getIntExtra("_b", 0); 
        //0 is the default argument is nothing is passed.
        d = thisIntent.getIntExtra("_d", 0); //same idea as above.

            c = fillList(); 

            /*this creates a new cursor adapter
            @param Context is the list context that you will be filling. 
            @param int layout is the layout that you will use for the rows
            @param Cursor is the cursor that was returned from the query
            @param from is the column names
            @param to is the layout ids that the fields will be put in. 
            @param from is the column names to map from
            @param to is the layout ids that the column fields will be put in. 
            */
            SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c, colsfrom, to);
            setListAdapter(myAdapter);
   }

private Cursor fillList() {
    DBHelper DbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    Cursor cursor;
    String wHERE = "_id = " + b + " AND Day_id = " + d ; 

    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();  
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle){
        throw sqle; 
    }

    cursor = myDbHelper.getDrinks(DATABASE_TABLE, colsfrom, wHERE, null, null,null, null);

    myDbHelper.close();

    return cursor;

}
```

When i put the contents of fillList() in the onCreate() it displays data just fine. When i pull it out it gives me the ERROR. Why is this happening? If anyone has a better way of going about this i would love to read it. Or we can play a game called "What stupid thing am i doing wrong Now? 
Thankyou.

EDIT:From DBHelper

```
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }
```

I am thinking that my problem line is the super.close() I believe that this line closes the database and anything affiliated with it which means the cursor that i try to use after its closed. I may be wrong though. Please explain if you can.

Comment: your fillList() has no param, how can you pass fillList(b,d) in your onCreate methode ?

Comment: Lol typo. that is actually not there because b and d are declared above.

Comment: On which other place you use fillList() ?

Comment: eventually i will use it to query the database again after changing "d" and repopulate the list accordingly from the new cursor. I already tried doing that but got the same result. So i went back to basics and found the ERROR. So i am trying to fix that before i use fllList anywhere else.

Comment: DBHelper DbHelper = new DBHelper(this); This could be problem if fillList is called in AsyncTask for example

Comment: fillList is not called in asnctask. If i did that i would have to pass a context and use that i believe.

Comment: I think i found it. Dunno wher eit is comming from though. DBHelper maybe? 11-15 03:03:21.387: E/Database(12387): close() was never explicitly called on database 'testdata'   and this                                                          11-15 03:03:21.387: E/Database(12387): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

Comment: My problem does in fact come down to when i issue the DBHelper.close() command. I cannot close it until i have set the cursor adapter. Because i am trying to open and query outside of where i set the adapter the database gets closed on me before things get displayed.

Comment: I have solved this problem. I will post the answer in 6 hours or when i wake up next because i am not cool enough to answer my own question within 8 hours of asking it. Thanks for your help. My biggest contributors were the ones asking for my stacktrace. That is what led me to the problem being outside the initial code that i submitted. Next time i will do a better job debugging and looking at the trace before i question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is right here, in your `fillList()`:

```
myDbHelper.close(); // <--- here
return cursor;
```

you make a cursor object but close your database connection before you even get to use it (this component of the database) which would render it useless or null if you would. Usually you close the cursor *and then* the database. But that's not throwing the error. That error *specifically* is because you hooked up this cursor to a cursorAdapter trying to fill your listView with nothing. Move that and it should be gone.

So where do you move it then? If you have a cursor hooked up to listView, it needs to be open the entire time, otherwise you'll get another error saying "attempting to re-open an already closed object". I'd suggest putting in the `onDestroy()` when then listView is being chucked as well.

Answer (score 0):

YaY Solved. Mango is exactly correct. Thankyou for you suggestion to close cursor in on destroy. I am not sure if the super.close() line closes my cursor or not. but i will look into it. I am also going to put the database query in async task for kicks and giggles.

I simply moved the two lines that created a new SimpleCursorAdapter and set the list view into the fillList method.

I also implemented my buttons and just added fillList at the end.
Here is the code that fixed things. Simple Mistake.

```
private void fillList() {
DBHelper DbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
Cursor cursor;
String wHERE = "_id = " + b + " AND Day_id = " + d ; 

try {
    myDbHelper.openDataBase();  
}
catch(SQLException sqle){
    throw sqle; 
}

cursor = myDbHelper.getDrinks(DATABASE_TABLE, colsfrom, wHERE, null, null,null, null);
SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, colsfrom, to);
setListAdapter(myAdapter);
myDbHelper.close();
 }
```

And Here is wehre i call the fillList again that updates my list view.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {

    //Mess with d based on button click
    }
    fillList();
}
```

Now the application has to create a new simple cursor adapter every time something is changed. 
If anyone has any ideas on implementing this without creating a new CursorAdapter every time that would help very much but my initial problem is solved. Thankyou for your help. Just the fact that you wanted to see my stack trace told me that i was not doing anything wrong in the code that i initially presented and i forgot that i made my dbHelper close all connections. Thankyou mango. I solved this last night but couldnt post it. Thanks for the explanation good sir. If you have any insight to the constant creation of a new cursoradapter i would be very pleased to see it. Maybe i need to fix the super.close() command somehow.

Comment: I agree android documentation hasn't been especially verbose about this topic. The way to do cursors these days, with all the trim and fixings, is to implement a `cursorLoader` class. i'd actually suggest it to you because you're talking about using asyncTask for your queries which the `cursorLoader` does natively-among other things like auto-reload. But if you just want a more crass method for just the one task, there are plently of options. `Cursor c = myDbHelper.getDrin...; \n -> myAdapter.changeCursor(c);` Basically you make another cursor and have your adapter swap the old for new.

Comment: Please note that the simpleCursorAdapter also has a method called `.swapCursor(c)`. But the disadvantage in using this is that it doesn't automatically close the pre-existing cursor like `.changeCursor(c)` will.

Comment: Thankyou Mango. Both Cursor Loader and Swap Cursor Use API 11. When i first started i decided to write for API 10 to start. I have been reading a lot about supporting the higher SDKs even debating on just building for Api 11 but the actual device that i am working on is 2.3.3 which i believe is api 10. Best Practices question. Is it better to build for the latest api and work fixes in for the older ones? or build for low api and add in the features of the later ones? This is getting a little outside the scope of this question but directly relating to my situation.

Comment: I love this Post even though it is a little old. I hope it is still common practice because i like the idea of extending the newer API version and Overriding the needed changes for the old api's [Ice and Cake](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html)

Comment: personally i don't exactly know if both routes pan out with any practical differences. If you want to support incompatible API versions, then you need separate methods for methods not supported by an API. I guess i'm just saying that no matter what your mindset is, your end result & technique is the same. So unless i'm missing something, i don't know.